# Class_weight for SVM classifier in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have a set of parameters to choose the best ones for svm.SVC classifier using GridSearchCV:

```
X=dataset.ix[:, dataset.columns != 'class']
Y=dataset['class']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.5)

clf=svm.SVC()
params=
        {'kernel':['linear', 'rbf', 'poly', 'sigmoid'],
         'C':[1, 5, 10],
         'degree':[2,3],
         'gamma':[0.025, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],
         'coef0':[2, 5, 9],
         'class_weight': [{1:10}, 'balanced']}

searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, params, cv=9, n_jobs=-1, scoring=f1)
searcher.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

And i get the error: `ValueError: class_weight must be dict, 'auto', or None, got: 'balanced'`
Why do I have it, if in instructions of svm parameters there is `'balanced'`, not `'auto'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'balanced'` should be working as you can see in line 51 or 74 [https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py](http://sklearn%20utils%20github)

Execute `sklearn.__version__` to check what version you are running.